# Cython OpenMP compiler flag

Tags: python, openmp, cython

as in http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html,
I put the compiler flags "-fopenmp" in the 'setup.py' file.

It compiles ok, but returns this: "cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'" and there is no speed up on the parallel code.

Using Cython 0.15.1, Python 2.7.2, Windows 7 , MinGW 32x.

Answer (score 4):

You are using MSVC compiler `cl.exe`. For MSVC compiler, you should give `/openmp` compiler option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw509c3b

Comment: My cython setup is weird. With only MinGW it give me the "vcvarsall.bat" error (not found i think). I tried every solution on web and nothing work. Then I install visual express 2008 and everything work perfectly(a web solution too). 

With option "/openmp":
Now it give me: "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'omp.h': No such file or directory"

Then I search for it and put into VC include dir and now I receive a lot of errors like this:
"omp.h(37) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '__attribute__'"